# Splash Screen em Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Até o momento está tudo bem, porém fiz um *splash screen* e coloquei o mesmo para rodar no *form* principal e rodava perfeitamente. Depois de um tempo eu atualizando sempre o projeto com novas funções e o principal do *splash* carrega, porém não mostra a imagem.

Já deletei e até recriei novamente, porém não dá certo e não sei se existe opção que limpa o *debug* do projeto.

Até já fiz o teste de deletar as pasta do *debug* também para ser recriado e nada.

Comment: Para limpar é em debug -> clean solution.  
Você inseriu a imagem usando qual componente?

Comment: @SNOT, por favor marque alguma resposta ou poste a solução se já tiver solucionado a questão.

Comment: Não teve solução, tive que refazer o projeto do zero para dar certo, deve ter bugado algum coisa que não sei dizer o que é

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema precisa de mais detalhamento para ser solucionado, mais uma coisa que sempre faço quando ocorrem problemas de compilação estranhos como o descrito é seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Conferir as referencias de bibliotecas de terceiros;
2. Conferir a compilação das bibliotecas que desenvolvi;
3. Verificar a versão do .net de todos os projetos (O ideal é todos estarem na mesma compilação, um problema que ocorre sempre nos projetos que crio é que eles vem por padrão na versão ***Client Profile*** e as minhas bibliotecas estão na versão completa e isso gera erro de compilação.

Se nada disso funcionar ai eu faço o seguinte:

1. Fechar o Visual Studio;
2. Deletar o conteúdo da pasta `bin` (verificar se não tem nenhum processo VSHost rodando no diretório;
3. Deletar o conteúdo da a pasta `obj`;
4. Recompilar todos os projetos da solução usando a opção Build -> Batch Build (primeiro eu dou um clean em todos os projetos e depois dou um Build, ou simplesmente chamo o Rebuild);

Answer (score 0):

Veja se a informação abaixo ajuda você na sua dúvida, pois para splash tem uma sequência.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]